# Subdomains redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain

With my current PHP knowledge, I know how to create a subdomain automatically via Plesk api when a user is created on my site. I can then redirect the `user.example.com` to `example.com/user` via htaccess.

My question that I cannot figure out how to do, is **how to redirect but also keep `user.example.com` in the navigation bar, not the `example.com/user`** ?

I own a dedicated hosting environment so I have access to change pretty much any setting that I like.

Comment: Why do you need to redirect at all? The subdomain should be able to load the data from a specific directory without the need of redirecting.

Comment: That is a good point actually...

Comment: You don't want to redirect at all, you want to internally rewrite requests, if at all. However I would strongly advise against adding the user name to the path, it will cause endless issues. Instead you can take the username from the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST]` superglobal entry.

Answer (score -1):

Here are some suggestions:
Don't use .htaccess for this. A very common use of .htaccess is to redirect all requests to a central file (generally index.php).
In order to allow dynamic subdomains you need to make sure your virtual host is configured properly for that.
And in order to redirect to the subdomain url you can use the built-in php function header. 
Example:

```
header('Location: '.$subdomainUrl);
```

Comment: I think he doesn't want to re-direct to sub-domain URL.. instead he wishes to serve `example.com/user` ...

Comment: @hacker, here is a copy paste of what he asked for My question that I cannot figure out how to do, is how to redirect but also keep user.example.com in the navigation bar, not the example.com/user ?

Comment: Whoever gave me that -1 I am interested in feedback. Be positive.

Comment: It was me, wait for 24 hours before I can remove downvote.

Comment: @hacker315, why 24 hours and it's been more than 24 hours.

Comment: it now shows `Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited.`.. Don't worry I have already upvoted your comments to make up for it mate..!